# Why Debug doesn't work after Visual Studio update?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019

I have updated Visual Studio 2019 from 16.6.1 version to 16.11.23 version. The update operation was finished successfully. When I want to run my MVC project in Debug mode, nothing happens. No error is displayed, the app is not running. What do I have to do to make it work?

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: Can you post build output log, build options...etc. ?

Comment: Where can I find what you requested?

Comment: build log is usually under View>Output. Build options are under Build>Configuration Manager.

Comment: you can also increase MSBuild Project build output verbosity to see more what happens during/after a build.

Comment: Please see the edited post. The Output window is empty.

Comment: I tested this on my side, and I can use this VS version to debug MVC project with no problem. I suggest you try to close the VS, go to the source directory of your MVC solution, show the hidden items in the directory, delete the .vs folder, and then reopen the VS to re-generate the debug settings. If this still not work, I suggest you to try to repair the VS via vs tool installer. :)

Comment: Hi lonut, any update of this issue? :)

Comment: Hi,
Sorry for not leaving a reply!
I had an issue with my browsing app, Microsoft Edge. After fixing it, I managed to Debug my project. Many thanks for your time and effort!